# MIPS: Using labels with memory offsets like $sp, doable? Bad practice?

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

I have a programming situation where a stack would work beautifully for my purposes. I was wondering if it was possible to use memory offset values in a similar manner to say, $sp, when addressing this allocated space.

IE:

```
.data
char_stack: .space 24

.text
main:
addi $t0, $zero, 18
sw $t0, 2(char_stack)
```

To save a value to the second byte of character stack? If my values are wrong but the idea is right, please let me know about the idea - the values are purely exemplary of what I wish to do.

Is this terrible practice? Something I should really avoid doing?
If it isn't, but there isn't a way to do this, is the closest approximation using 'la' and an increment register?

(I'm using SPIM to simulate MIPS)

Also, I'm dealing with writing most of this in an exception handler (weird assignment) so I can't really make use of $SP all that effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it be a terrible practice ? I don't understand what do you fear. If you were describing the exact problem you're willing to solve with a custom stack then maybe we'd have better inisght of whether this is terrible practice. In this case your stack has space for 24 bytes, not a terribly big stack but depending on what you're trying to do it *could* be sufficient.

However the addressing mode you seem to be using `offset(offset)` is wrong and doesn't exist, on MIPS only `offset(register)` is available. (You could use `offset(zero)` to simulate it, but anyway I don't think it's what you wanted to do here.)

Instead, you'd want to initialize a register (stack pointer) to `char_stack` once in your program, and then increase it as you push data on your stack, decrease it as you pop.

I insist that `sp` is just an alias for `r29` which is conventionally the stack pointer, but any other register is suitable as a local pointer to another stack.

If you only use this custom stack in a part of your program and want the register to be free for general usage elsewhere in the rest of your program, store it to a dedicated place in memory when you leave, and load it back when you enter back in your routine that uses the custom stack.

Comment: I need to write characters to a memory mapped output buffer, to make a timer, so my idea was to use a stack to make the loop for output much more intuitive, since i have to do this char by char. hence the use of a stack (thoug mine will be seven bytes for mm : ss)

Comment: Honnestly, I don't know why you're calling this a *stack*. A stack is a data structure where you push extra elements in and can pull them out later, in First-In-Last-Out order. It seems you'd rather want to have a *buffer* of 7 bytes.